# Comparing items of lists using assertEqual

Tags: python

```
list_num = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
new_list = set()

def duplicado(list_num):
    for i in list_num:
        if list_num.count(i) >= 2:
            new_list.add(i)
    print(list(new_list))
    print(list_num)

duplicado(list_num)


import unittest

class Pruebas(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num),new_list)

unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

I have an error that says:

```
self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num),new_list)
```

this is the error I'm been given. I want to assert the values of new_list[2,3] to the values of list_num. It's an exercise class, the question as follows:

> Find All Duplicates in an Array
>
> Given an array of integers, 1 ≤ a[i] ≤ n (n = size of array), some
> elements appear twice and others appear once.
>
> Find all the elements that appear twice in this array.
>
> Example:
>
> Input: [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
>
> Output: [2,3]

I've tried asserCountEqual, and assertEqual

```
AssertionError: None != {2, 3}

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Your `duplicado` function is returning None. I think you must `return new_list`

Comment: now, is comparing both, but with this error `AssertionError: [4, 3, 2, 7, 8, 2, 3, 1] != {2, 3}`

Comment: Where is this from? Does it really not say anything about the order of the result?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is: `AssertionError: None != {2, 3}` because of this line here:

```
self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num),new_list)
```

You're checking whether the return value of `duplicado(list_num)` equals `new_list`.

The problem is that your function's return value is `None` because there is no return statement.

Jailton Silva's comment isn't quite right either because you would just be returning the list you got as a parameter without changing anything.

To fix this put `new_list = set()` inside the duplicado function, swap the `print(list(new_list))` to `return list(new_list)` and remove the `print(list_num)` line.

Also, when unit testing you should check against fixed values so in the `self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num),new_list)` line you should make it `self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num),[2,3])`

Comment: i've done this and it works! but now i don't output new_list and list_num... what shoud I do? to print both lists

Comment: @GonlinNocturno I'm not sure I understand what what you mean by output. The test works so the output is correct. If you want the list to show up on the screen you can keep using the print statements.

Comment: I meant that i get print [2,3] and [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1] twice, is this normal as the unittest works that way, without the unitesting i get one one print of each list

Comment: @GonlinNocturno Yes, its normal. Every time you call the function its going to print the result. You call it once normally and then twice in the test. Two calls, two prints.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicado function is returning None. You must return new_list

```
list_num = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]
new_list = set()
def duplicado(list_num):
    for i in list_num:
        if list_num.count(i) >= 2:
            new_list.add(i)

    print(list(new_list))
 
    print(list_num)
    return new_list  # <-- This return was missing

import unittest

class Pruebas(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(duplicado(list_num), new_list)  # It will be used here

unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of issues with your code.  As others have stated, your `duplicado` function is not returning anything.

Fix that, then ask yourself what the purpose of `AssertEquals` is.  This should be comparing the result of running your code against what you expect the answer to be.  That is, the `AssertEquals` is testing if you got the right answer.  But where is that right answer in your code?  You haven't supplied what you think is the right answer to your code, so how can it check for that?  You need to include the correct answer in your code.

Here's a version of your program that solves these and other issues:

```
list_num = [4,3,2,7,8,2,3,1]

def duplicado(list_num):
    new_list = set()
    for i in list_num:
        if list_num.count(i) >= 2:
            new_list.add(i)
    return sorted(list(new_list))


import unittest

# Correct result must be in ascending sorted order
correct = [2, 3]

class Pruebas(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        result = duplicado(list_num)
        self.assertEqual(result, correct)

unittest.main(argv=['first-arg-is-ignored'], exit=False)
```

Result:

```
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
OK

Ran 1 test in 0.002s
OK
```

Comment: Ah, good point.  My goal was only to fix the structural issues with the code.  But that doesn't fully answer the question.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Actually I think it should do `self.assertEqual(sorted(result), correct)` instead, as the problem statement doesn't require any particular order and thus the solver function should be allowed to produce any, and it's the checker's job to handle it. Or better yet, [`assertCountEqual`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertCountEqual`) appears to exist for exactly this.

Comment: That's for example how LeetCode judges it, you can see it [accepted my `[3, 2]`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQRcs.png).